# Check if element is in hashset

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashset

How can I check whether a `hashset` contains a particular value or not in `javascript`? I have tried the following which is not working:

```
if (hashset.contains(finalDate)) {
    alert("inside if");
}
```

My js code:

```
$.each(cdata.lines, function(idx, line){
    // line.hashsetvariable is my hashset which contain all dates and 
    // let finaldate is 2012-19-12 
    // I want to check this date in my hashset.
}
```

Comment: post the code which defines your hashset and also which defines your finalDate

Comment: Can you please post the values of `hashset` and `finalDate`

Comment: Does `hashset` come from some sort of jQuery plugin?

Comment: Yes Asad my js code is below:$.each(cdata.lines, function(idx, line){here line.hashsetvariable is my hashset.}

Comment: That does not really explain what `hashset` is. There is no "hashset" in JavaScript, so you have to be specific about which data structures/types you use.

Answer (score 3):

If the hash set you mean is an object (or hash...) then you can check whether it contains a key by:

```
var hash = { foo: 'bar', baz: 'foobar' };
'foo' in hash;
```

If you look for particular value:

```
function containsValue(hash, value) {
    for (var prop in hash) {
        if (hash[prop] === value) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you want to do something more "global" (I don't recommend!) you can change Object's prototype like:

```
Object.prototype.containsValue = function (value) {
    for (var prop in this) {
        if (this[prop] === value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

In this case:

```
var test = { foo: 'bar' };
test.containsValue('bar'); //true
test.containsValue('foobar'); //false
```